# How to get field dependency like feature in visualforce page using javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, javascript, json

I have a VF page which needs to have only html controls. 
I have an object

FieldType__c - Name field will have 3 values (Type1, Type2, Type3).

My VF page has to show the records of FieldType__c. Against each record of FieldType__c, there should be a dropdownlist that needs to show a particular set of values.

I am new to salesforce and want to know the best way to get this functionality. Right now I am saving the possible dropdownlist values in a custom object, 
Valueset__c- Name field saves the values to be shown in the dropdownlist and a lookup field to fieldType__c object.

I also use a wrapper class that would hold the FieldType__c and the related records in Valueset__c

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  standardController="Filedtypes__c" applyHTmlTag="false" extensions="FieldtypesController" >  
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jqueryui, '/jquery-ui-1.12.1/external/jquery/jquery.js')}"  />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jqueryui, '/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js')}"  />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" >
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">               
            <table id="tblfieldlist">   
            </table>

            <script>

            var j$=jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(document).ready(function(){
                GetAllFieldTypes();
            });

            function GetAllFieldTypes()
            {
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.FieldtypesController.GetAllFieldTypes}',
                    function(result,event){
                        if (event.status){
                            console.log(result);
                            var fieldList = JSON.parse(result); 
                            console.log(fieldList.length);
                            var trData = '';
                            for(var i=0;i<fieldList.length;i++)
                            {
                                trData +='<tr>';
                                trData +='<td style="height:25px;" valign="top">' + ((fieldList[i].f.Name==undefined)?"":fieldList[i].f.Name) + '</td>';
                                trData += '<td>' + '<select>'

                                for(var j=0;j<fieldList[i].statustypes.length;j++)
                                {
                                trData += '<option>'+fieldList[i].statustypes[j].Name+'</option>'
                                }
                                trData += '</select>'+ '</td>';                                    
                                trData +='</tr>';
                            }
                            j$("#tblfieldlist").append(trData);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(event.message); 
                        }               
                    },
                    {escape:false}
                );

            }
            </script>

        </html>            
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex code

```
global with sharing class FieldtypesController {
public FieldtypesController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{ }

class Wrapper
{
    Filedtypes__c fType;
    List<valueset__c> statusValues;
}

@RemoteAction
global static string GetAllFieldTypes()
{
    List<Filedtypes__c> lst =  [SELECT Name FROM Filedtypes__c];
    List<Wrapper> lstwrp = new List<Wrapper>();
    for (Filedtypes__c i : lst) {
        Wrapper wrp = new Wrapper();
        wrp.fType = i;
        wrp.statusValues = [SELECT Name FROM valueset__c where FieldType__c = :i.id];
        lstwrp.add(wrp);
    }     
    return Json.serializepretty(lstwrp);
}}
```

My page looks like the attached image. [image]

Comment: What does this question have to do with `Apex` or `SOQL`? Right now, your question is a bit of a wall of text and difficult to parse and understand. Can you break up your explanation into more digestible chunks?

Comment: I felt the solution might need apex and SOQL too. Updated my question now. Added the apex code too. Hope this will be easy for the readers to understand.